# Как добавить столбец в базy данных sqlite3 python, с объяснением каждого слова после cursor.execute

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

```
c.execute("alter table linksauthor add column '%s' 'float'" % author)
```

Объяните, что какое слово значит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alter` - изменить

`table` - таблицу

`linksauthor` - название таблицы, которую менять

`add` - добавить

`column` - колонку

`'%s'` - сюда будет подставлено название добавляемой колонки

`'float'` - тип добавляемой колонки - число с плавающей точкой

`% author` - подставить название колонки из переменной author